# Offline install wi-fi drivers on old PC using Linux Mint 15

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, drivers, wifi

I want to use wi-fi connection on my old notebook on which the Linux Mint 15 is installed, but I can't because it doesn't see any available installed drivers on it.

I have searched many website and read different variations of setup, but no success.

I have installed offline the b43-fwcutter perfectly, which is needed for wi-fi driver configuration, but have problems with activating driver.

Some details about my settings on Linux Mint:

```
iwconfig
```

shows:

1). lo no wireless extensions eth0

2). no wireless extensions

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

shows:

FATAL: Module wl not found

```
sudo lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
```

shows me , that I have 4311 version of the device

```
rfkill list
```

shows be , that neither software nor hardware is blocked

if in the GUI mode (in my desktop environment) I click on the wireless icon, nothing appears

in the application manager I haven't installed the STA broadcom drivers

if to open Wireless Network drivers utillity in Mint , it doesn't show me any driver

I also was trying to onstall `wl_apsta.o` with the next command

```
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware wl_apsta.o
```

all was extracting pretty fine

but when I try to

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

nothing happens

How to make work Wi-Fi with the Mint 15 perfectly in offline mode?

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L. Please include the _actual_ output of commands rather than describing it. Especially the output of `lspci`. I _think_ you have a BCM43224 card, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the best case scenario where your card has the BCM43224 or similar chipset, you should be able to do this:

1. Download [`module-assistant`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/module-assistant) and [`wireless-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/wireless-tools). I assume you have access to the internet somehow or you would not have been able to post. So, download these two packages and save them to your hard drive.
2. Install both packages (I have used the 64bit one but take the one for your architecture):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i module-assistant_0.11.4_all.deb
   sudo dpkg -i wireless-tools_30~pre9-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. As root, run the following commands:

   ```
   m-a a-i broadcom-sta
   echo blacklist brcm80211 >> /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf
   update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
   modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcm80211
   modprobe wl
   ```

Useful resources:

- http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/218 (for Mint Debian but the idea is the same)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but this is the setup that I am now working on LIVE at this Moment..!!!!!

I have a Gigabyte E1500 Laptop with Wireless Capability.
I created a USB Distro to boot the Laptop and load Mint 15 in the Distro Capability without installing Mint 15 to just try and test it.
I have a Virgin Media account with a Netgear Router

The steps I took were:-
Settings - Network Connections - Add - Wifi _ Create 
WiFi Page - SSID (Enter the SSID of the Router)
Security Page - WPA & WPA2 Personal (Enter the Password of the Router)
Save

Lo and behold it works. And I have no reason to believe it should not work as you install the System onto your Hard drive.